# "Build with Jekyll" error while trying to puplish a page to my github site

Tags: github, jekyll

[image: Error Code]

My github is super rusty but I am trying to push a simple markdown page with a movie review onto my github website but it won't show. I usually work on GitHub desktop but then I went to the site and saw that this "Build with Jekyll" has been 'X'ed out.

I have NO IDEA what this means. I posted another page few days ago and don't believe I did anything differently this time.

I am more of an analyst(SQL) person at the moment and I learned all of this coding like a decade ago but I really want to become more active on my blog so any help would be appreicated.

[image: few days ago]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the build log (click on the x-ed out entry), you will see this log:

```
Run actions/jekyll-build-pages@v1
/usr/bin/docker run --name ghcrioactionsjekyllbuildpagesv104_1df267 --label 290506 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_SOURCE" -e "INPUT_DESTINATION" -e "INPUT_FUTURE" -e "INPUT_BUILD_REVISION" -e "INPUT_VERBOSE" -e "INPUT_TOKEN" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL" -e "ACTIONS_ID_TOKEN_REQUEST_TOKEN" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/stutichugh.github.io/stutichugh.github.io":"/github/workspace" ghcr.io/actions/jekyll-build-pages:v1.0.4
  Logging at level: debug
Configuration file: /github/workspace/./_config.yml
      GitHub Pages: github-pages v227
      GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.9.2
             Theme: jekyll-theme-primer
      Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0
         Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata
To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
YAML Exception reading /github/workspace/2021-09-15-comedy.html: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 2 column 1 
  Liquid Exception: Liquid error (line 93): Cannot sort a null object. in /_layouts/post.html
...
```

There are two sorts in the post layout. The error says that one of `page.categories` or `page.tags` is null.

I have refactored the layout code in question a little bit. Both loops have a check for an empty array now, see the category example below:

```
{% assign categories = page.categories %}
{% if categories.size > 0 %}
...
```

Full code for both loops:

```
{% assign categories = page.categories %}
{% if categories.size > 0 %}
<div class="after-post-cats">
    <ul class="tags mb-4">
        <p>Categories:</p>
        {% assign sortedCategories = categories | sort %}
        {% for category in sortedCategories %}
        <li>
            <a class="smoothscroll" href="{{site.baseurl}}/categories#{{ category | replace: " "," -" }}">{{
                category }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}

{% assign tags = page.tags %}
{% if tags.size > 0 %}
<div class="after-post-tags">
    <ul class="tags">
        <p>Tags:</p>
        {% assign sortedTags = tags | sort %}
        {% for tag in sortedTags %}
        <li>
            <a class="smoothscroll" href="{{site.baseurl}}/tags#{{ tag | replace: " "," -" }}">#{{ tag
                }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

This needs to go into _layouts/posts.html.

The easiest solution to fix the build error: Move the post md file(s) from the project root into the _posts folder.

Comment: As mentioned before there have been posts outside the _posts directory, here's the fix: https://github.com/stutichugh/stutichugh.github.io/pull/6

Comment: Hey @Christian I am facing a similar issue, I guess for files to be published in Jeykll they need to have a specific folder structure. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: @AjayKushwaha please post a new question, you can still refer to this one but of course, we need the details.